# Which is the better way to design a react tabs component?

Tags: reactjs, react-component

I'm developing a react tabs component. There are 2 styles when it comes to its `props` interface design.

One is passing the `Tab.TabPane` components as the `children` prop to the `Tabs` component:

```js
const App = () => (
  <Tabs defaultActiveKey="1">
    <Tabs.TabPane tab="Tab 1" key="1">
      Content of Tab Pane 1
    </Tabs.TabPane>
    <Tabs.TabPane tab="Tab 2" key="2">
      Content of Tab Pane 2
    </Tabs.TabPane>
    <Tabs.TabPane tab="Tab 3" key="3">
      Content of Tab Pane 3
    </Tabs.TabPane>
  </Tabs>
)
```

And the other is directly passing the `items` prop to the `Tabs` component:

```js
const App = () => (
  <Tabs
    items={[
      {
        label: `Tab 1`,
        key: '1',
        children: `Content of Tab Pane 1`,
      },
      {
        label: `Tab 2`,
        key: '2',
        children: `Content of Tab Pane 2`,
      },
      {
        label: `Tab 3`,
        key: '3',
        children: `Content of Tab Pane 3`,
      },
    ]}
  />
);
```

Can anyone explain which style is better from the following perspectives？

1. DV(development experience). Which one is easier and more convenient to use?
2. code readability
3. performance

Comment: Number 1 and 2 goes to the former for sure. (Maybe not Tabs.TabPane, though; just Tab or TabPane would be better)

Comment: @caTS Why the first style is better?